# How execute a TQuickRep (quickreport) without displaying or printing it?

Tags: delphi, export-to-pdf, silent, quickreports

I need run a report (TQuickRep) for export only, without printing or showing.
The Prepare method does nothing.
The beforeprints or afterprints events doesn´t fires.

Ex.

```
var rep: TMyQuickRep; //TMyQuickRep is a report TQuickRep
begin
  rep := TMyQuickRep.Create(Self);
  try
    rep.SomeData := somedata;
    rep.DataSet  := somDataSet;
    rep.Prepare;
    //rep.Run? there isn´t a method for run
    rep.ExportToFilter(TQRPDFDocumentFilter.Create('c:\temp\myreport.pdf'));  
    //pdf is an empty page
  finally
    FreeAndNil(rep);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried printing it after setting the active printer to the`Microsoft Print to PDF` device?

Comment: No, I don´t need printing. I need create pdf file in silent mode, and show it into a navigator. With FastReports it's easy.

Comment: Then why not use FastReports?

Comment: QR does not have this function by default, we use third-party components for export to PDF, especially for legacy reports that we do not want to convert to FR. This is one of the many reasons to not use QR and switch to FR, which is better in all aspects.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will use FR then! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...( I was looking for a solution just like this and the code below worked for me.)

```
rep.ExportToFilter(TQRPDFDocumentFilter.Create('c:\temp\myreport.pdf')); 
rep.Print;
```